# how to generate a file by fixed position with awk windows

Tags: shell, batch-file, awk

I have an awk command line developed in unix and I have to pass it to windows. I have installed the gawk tool for windows, I have configured my environment variable and finally I have converted the shell to batch but when I run the .bat it generates an empty file.

this is my code: file.bat

```
echo off
set "fecha=%1"
set "inputpath=%2"
set "unique=.uq"
set file=FICUO%fecha%.txt
echo %fecha%
echo %file%
awk "{!x[$1,$2,$6,$8,$9,$12,$16,$17,$33]++}" FIELDWIDTHS="3 19 19 3 3 5 12 6 9 40 4 8 13 3 3 3 3 1 3 13 13 13 13 13 13 3 13 2 8 8 8 2 8 6 11 11 11 8 4" %inputpath%%file% > %inputpath%%file%%unique%
```

I assume that the problem is the FIELDWITHS option, I have been researching about it and I find how to indicate the fixed position of the fields.

this is an example input flat file

```
2110004757960000000036000475796000332797200902200300000008067260007588013568776xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                         54112015123000000002621706040000080030000000000026217000000000327710000000032771000000000000000000000000000000000032771031000000000000025201603252016042000000000  20151230000000000000010000000000000000000001000000000000000
2310004757960000000036000475796000332797200902200300000008067260007588013568776xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                         54112015123000000002621706040000080040000000000026217000000000327710000000032771000000000000000000000000000000000032771030000000000000025201604252016052000000000  20151230000000000000010000000000000000000001000000000000000
```

any idea what could be my error so that it does not print anything in the output file, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not `FIELDWIDTHS`, it's that you have the condition that could trigger a `print` buried in an action. Change:

```
{!x[$1,$2,$6,$8,$9,$12,$16,$17,$33]++}
```

to:

```
!x[$1,$2,$6,$8,$9,$12,$16,$17,$33]++
```

so the result is treated as a condition that could trigger the default `print` action. I'm assuming the intent is to print unique lines from the input. FWIW we idiomatically name the array used in that context `seen` rather than `x` and it makes your code easier to understand if you declare your variables before they're used, i.e. at the start of the script, rather than after they're used:

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="3 19 19 3 3 5 12 6 9 40 4 8 13 3 3 3 3 1 3 13 13 13 13 13 13 3 13 2 8 8 8 2 8 6 11 11 11 8 4" "!seen[$1,$2,$6,$8,$9,$12,$16,$17,$33]++" %inputpath%%file% > %inputpath%%file%%unique%
```

If you want the output to be tab-separated fields then:

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="3 19 19 3 3 5 12 6 9 40 4 8 13 3 3 3 3 1 3 13 13 13 13 13 13 3 13 2 8 8 8 2 8 6 11 11 11 8 4" -v OFS="\t" "{key=$1 OFS $2 OFS $6 OFS $8 OFS $9 OFS $12 OFS $16 OFS $17 OFS $33} !seen[key]++{print key}" %inputpath%%file% > %inputpath%%file%%unique%
```

Sorry I don't know windows syntax so hopefully you know what to do with this if I got the quotes wrong or something.